# why word ladder problem works different on GFG and leetcode?

Tags: string, algorithm, graph

In this question we have to print the all minimum size string to reach the target word. When i solve this question on GFG, it runs fine but not on LeetCode.

Here is my code:

```
class Solution {
    public:
        vector<vector<string>> findSequences(string beginWord, string endWord, vector<string>& wordList) {
            unordered_set<string> st(wordList.begin(), wordList.end());
            queue<vector<string>> p;
            p.push({beginWord});
            vector<string> usedOnLevel;
            usedOnLevel.push_back(beginWord);
            int level = 0;
            vector<vector<string>> ans;

            while (!p.empty()) {
                vector<string> vec = p.front();
                p.pop();
                
                if (vec.size() > level) {
                    level++;
                    for (auto it : usedOnLevel) {
                        st.erase(it);
                    }
                }
                
                string word = vec.back();
                if (word == endWord) {
                    if (ans.size() == 0) {
                        ans.push_back(vec);
                    } else if (ans.size() > 0 && ans[0].size() == vec.size()) {
                        ans.push_back(vec);
                    }
                }
                
                for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                    char original = word[i];
                    for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
                        word[i] = ch;
                        if (st.find(word) != st.end()) {
                            usedOnLevel.push_back(word);
                            vec.push_back(word);
                            p.push(vec);
                            vec.pop_back();
                        }
                    }

                    word[i] = original;
                }
            }

            return ans;
        }
};
```

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. Don't expect us to visit third party sites to understand what you are raising here. Explain what goes wrong, which error message you get, for which input, and what was expected instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that leetcode throws bigger problems at you, and so correct code with poor performance is going to break.  And your code has poor performance.

Why?  Well, for a start, for each word you find a path to, for each possible substitution, you're looking through all words to find yours.  So  suppose I start with all of the 5 letter words in the official Scrabble dictionary.  There are about `9000` of those.  For each word you find you're going to come up with `26*5 = 130` possible new words, then search the entire `9000` word list for that for `1_170_000_000` word comparisons, mostly to find nothing.  Your algorithm wanted to do more than just that, but it has already timed out.

How could you make that faster?  Here is one idea.  Create a data structure to answer the following question:

```
by position of the deleted letter:
    by the resulting string:
        list of words that matched
```

For the entire Scrabble dictionary this data structure only has around `45_000` entries.  And makes it easy to find all words next to a given word in the word ladder.

OK, great!  Is that enough?  Well...probably not.  You're starting from `startWord` and finding all chains of words you can find from there.  Most of which are going nowhere near `endWord` and represent wasted work.  If the minimum length chain is fairly long, this can easily be an exponential amount of wasted effort.  How can we avoid it?

The answer is to do a breadth-first search from `endWord` to find out how far away each word is from `endWord`.  In this search we can also record for each word which words moved you closer.  Again, even for all of the Scrabble dictionary, this data structure will be of manageable size.  And you can break it off as soon as you've found how to get to `startWord`.

But now with this pre-processing, it is easy to start with `startWord` and recursively find all solutions.  Because all of the work you'll be doing is enumerating paths that you already know will work.